# swift dismiss modal and push to new VC

Tags: swift, swift2, push, ios9, modalviewcontroller

I have tableview... 1 table showing a new modal window and when I press the button I want to dismiss the modal window and push to VC. My code only hide the modal view but no push is made.

```
    @IBAction func registrationBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let openNewVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("registrationVcID") as! RegistrationVC

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { () -> Void   in
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(openNewVC, animated: true)

            })
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a protocol

```
protocol View1Delegate: class {
    func dismissViewController(controller: UIViewController)
}
```

When you tap button on Register will call delegate back to TableView. TableViewController should implement:

```
  func dismissViewController(controller: UIViewController) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in
        //Perform segue or push some view with your code

    }
}
```

You can do anything in here. Push screen you want. Detail implement you can see my demo: [Demo Push View in Swift](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoPushView)

Comment: Whoa! thank you so much. I applied your project to my problem and it solved it! I like it.

Comment: For us newbies - "Create a protocol" - where?

Comment: @Donnelle check the demo

Comment: I love you. I no joke just spent about 8 hours trying to learn this part of Swift and understand it while solving a problem I was having in my app. You just solved my problem with your demo. You are a hero.

Answer (score 2):

Updated syntax for **Swift 3 and 4**

Dismissing view controllers

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or if you'd like to do something in a completion block (After the view has been dismissed) you can use...

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            // Your code here
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

self.navigationController won't do anything inside that completion block as it's already dismissed.

Instead create a delegate that you call on the parent view controller when dismissing the current one.

```
protocol PushViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func pushViewController(vc: UIViewController)
}
```

and then in your closing VC you can store delegate and call it in the completion block.

```
weak var delegate: PushViewControllerDelegate?

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: { () -> Void   in

    let openNewVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("registrationVcID") as! RegistrationVC
    self.delegate?.pushViewController(openNewVC)
}
```

And the implementation in your **presenting** view controller

```
//declaration
class OneController: UIViewController, PushViewControllerDelegate

//show modal
let twoController = TwoController()
twoController.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(twoController, animated:true)

//MARK: PushViewControllerDelegate

func pushViewController(vc: UIViewController) {
    self.navigationController?.push(vc, animated:true)
}
```

Comment: no, this is not working. It will dismiss and no push is happening

Comment: Yes. That won't work either, sorry. However, the delegate solution should work...

Comment: I put the protocol and wear var delegate + method in Modal window VC. Where shall i put the pushViewController?

Comment: In the VC that the modal is shown from. That VC needs to implement the delegate and then set itself as the delegate in the modal VC before it is shown.

Comment: Well I am lost now .... I have setup like this:
1) FavouriteVC(TableView-embed in navigation controller) ->
2) CreateProfileVC(Modal window) ->
3) RegistrationVC (final view navigation controller)
My question is...how to setup your solution?

Comment: So FavouriteVC is the OneController in my example and it should implement PushViewControllerDelegate as in the example. It also need to set itself as the delegate in CreateProfileVC (TwoController in my example).