# Is it possible to segue from a modal view to a view that is not in the hierarchy on a Navigation Controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

On my main view in a NavigationController I have a button that brings up a new view modally to submit a post. I have a button to dismiss this view which brings the user back to the main view, however if the users proceeds to make a post, I want it to dismiss the view and proceed to a show the post in the Navigation controller.

The ideal effect would have the standard navigation controller's back button on the top that can bring the user back to the main view when they have finished looking at their post.

I have tried several different methods, but I tend to get an error stating "Warning: Attempt to present (The View I Want to Show) whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Thanks for any info!

Comment: Use delegate or unwind to tell your main vc to show the view, not the one u dismiss

Comment: If you pass the navigation controller instance to the view controller you are presenting modally, you can modify the `viewControllers` property to have the post view controller at the top and then allow your modal view controller to be dismissed, revealing the post and a back button

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. This is the best way I've found to structure the app to allow this functionality.

- RootViewController

  - UINavigationViewController

    - ContentViewController (your current "main" view controller)

You're basically going to create a new RootViewController that is going to contain your current UINavigationController as a child. I usually setup the window.rootViewController programmatically in the AppDelegate. I would also keep a global reference to it.

Have a look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) on this. Basically, the RootViewController code would look like this:

```
[self addChildViewController:navController];
navController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
[self.view addSubview:self.navController.view];
[navController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Now, whenever you need to present a modal view controller, present it from the RootViewController, instead of the current/top view controller on the UINavigationBar. This allows you to manipulate the UINavigtaionController independently and you won't get the error you're seeing.

So present the modal view controller from the RootViewController, this covers the UINavigationController and its content (top view controller). Make any changes you need to the UINavigationController stack (push, pop, etc...) with no animation. When you're done dismiss the modal view controller (with animation) and it will show you're adjusted UINavigationController.

Hopefully, this all makes sense. It's kind of complex and hard to explain in text. :p

If you don't want to setup a RootViewController, you might want to try presenting the modal view controller from the UINavigationController, as that might have the same effect. From the view controller just do self.parentViewController.present.

The main thing you're trying to avoid is presenting a modal from a view controller and then removing that view controller (pop) before the modal is dismissed. The view controller that presents the view controller is responsible for dismissing it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it all working (I'm still new to Swift) and the two comments on the question were very helpful. The most helpful of all was the top answer here's example on github.
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806577/swift-dismiss-modal-and-push-to-new-vc)